# use tinytext in place of varchar

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ive got a fairly large database with about 30 tables. Each table contains about 30 columns, with about 350 records per table.  Im creating the table in Excel which saves me A LOT of time, I then use an excel to sql converter, and upload the converted file into a phpmyadmin database. Everything works great, except that the converted files' columns is of type tinytext rather than varchar.

All I would like to know is:

**If I continue using tinytext as the datatype will it cause me problems later on when I start writing code in PHP to use the data?** Keeping in mind that most of the columns contains both text and numbers

Comment: You should realy consider discarding Excel here. Maybe use a better MySQL client like http://www.heidisql.com/. And yes, the text variants are handled differently then the char/vchar variants. I'll try to find a list of differences (if noone is faster).

Comment: In short: no, it won't. Your database has very tiny size: `30*350*30<1000*350<1000000`. So you have less that 1 mil. values. It's _nothing_ - so with such sizes you may forget about your data type. It's about size only. `text/longtext` fields are stored separately, thus there may be performance impact, but it's too few data in your question to say that

Comment: `TEXT` columns can't be accessed and searched as efficiently as `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Btw, that many tables and columns suggest that your database structure  needs a rework. Maybe you can plan for such a rework in the near future?

Comment: Thank you that gave me peace of mind and answered my question

Comment: @ToBe that is what Im thinking aswell can you please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308334/need-help-creating-structure-to-database