# Need help creating structure to database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, data-structures

Im working on a website that processes statistics, for a sporting competition. I.E my site will let users quickly look up which player(s) scored the most points in a game/season or what 1 players record is against another players or team.

*My data for previous games are displayed like this*
[image]

*When you click on a round. Example round4 game1 (Which is Hurricanes vs Crusaders) The statistics for that game and all player statistics for that game (for both teams) gets displayed. As such:*

[image]

[image]

*Furthermore game statistics also gets displayed like this:*
[image]

Now im trying to upload this to a database, so that users can:

1. Compare 1 players record against another players record
2. Compare 1 players record against a specific team
3. Compare a teams record against another teams record
4. Display best and worst player and team statistics

This problem has kept me busy for 3 days, im at the stage now where Im starting to pull the hair out of my head. I just can not get an efficient way to link the tables together.

Should I create a table for each individual match? or Should I create 1 table for all matches and 1 table for all players? If so what do I work with as my primary keys?

I know this is a long question so to whomever took the time to read through this thank you in advance, if anyone could point me in the right direction or just give me an opinion it would be GREATLY appreciated. im just completely stumped on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the statistics at the lowest applicable level.  You want to apply the principles of database normalization to your initial design.  This gives you the most straight-forward data capture scenario while leaving you the most flexibility for reporting.

Once you decide exactly what reporting you need and have determined what performance challenges you may be facing, then you can apply *denormalization* to create reporting data warehouse tables.

Consider the following logical data model:

[image: ERD]

Comment: thank you sooo much for taking the time to draw up that diagram for me, a light bulb (finally) came on, im starting to grasp the design after looking at that diagram. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If the hope of teaching how to fish....

Write out what Entities you think you have, and what attributes they own. An attribute might be another Entity. For example a Team entity has a Name attribute, and multiple Player attributes. But Player is also an Entity with a Name attribute and maybe some Statistics attributes.

This will give you your starting point for Tables (Entities) and their columns (Attributes). Where an Attribute is also an Entity, draw a line from the Attribute to the Entity: those are your relationships. Then get hold of an example of putting data into Third Normal Form (3NF) and follow tghe example applying the steps to your diagram. When you've done that, you'll have a good DB Design.

Cheers -

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is a starting point and I will definitely use the advice

Comment: Good luck! If you run into problems along the way, post specific questions, along with the structure you've got so far. Cheers -

Answer (score 0):

You should join all your "Game" tables into one table. Just add the needed extra info:

Columns:

- gameId - int - game id, former part of table name
- scoreA - first teams score
- scoreB - second teams score
- teamAId - Id of first team, former name of column
- teamBId - Id of second team, former name of column

This would also enable you to do much more interesting searches and statistics on all of your games at once. And better yet, you have a flexible structure than can be used for any number of games and teams that may come in the future.

Comment: I think I mistook your posted tables as your actuall db structure. If so, this is a fairly uncomplex change. If your db structure is something else, plz post and we can try to go from there.

Comment: If you are free to start from scratch, the other posters have some usefull tips here!